# What are some ways to generate activity or review on lone answers?

Tags: discussion, answers, review

I've been scouring the unanswered questions and putting some research effort into my answers. However, often I find no activity on my answers. I have found that making edits to my answer or the question sometimes causes activity, but this is not consistent.

- **What's the best way to encourage users to review/check answers?** Specifically, lone answers to tumbleweed-type questions.
- **Similarly, what's the best way to find answers that need reviewing or checking?** I use review, but I am still limited to first posts and late answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Similarly, what's the best way to find answers that need reviewing or checking? I use review, but I am still limited to first posts and late answers.

There doesn't seem to be any easy way to do this, though I'd like to have one as well.

Try [this search](https://stackoverflow.com/search-new?q=answers:1&submit=search). It shows posts with a minimum of one answer, with the number of answers displayed next to the title. Just choose the questions with less votes and a few answers, and look for hidden gems.

Even better, set up a chat room and find a bunch of like-minded people willing to look for and vote on awesome but underappreciated questions. But don't use this to advertise your own posts, and make sure others don't, either. (otherwise it can be called vote-ringing, which is punishable). This is already done to some extent in most tag chat rooms, in fact--if someone sees a great answer in the tag, they post it.

If you see a *really* good answer that doesn't have too many votes, place a bounty on the q 
with the option "to reward an existing answer".

### Another option is to share good posts on G+/Twtter/FB

> What's the best way to encourage users to review/check answers? Specifically, lone answers to tumbleweed-type questions

Well ,you could set up a chatroom as shown before, and advertise it on various other chat rooms. Or you could push for a [meta-tag:feature request] on meta that lets us review such posts (maybe those with a high character count but low votes)

Answer (score 2):

I saw that your last three answered questions all have a bounty .. and

> The question gets placed in the home page's featured tab for seven days.

[From set a bounty on a question](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/set-bounties)

> [image]

Also like you, there are many more who want to answer bounty questions.

And if you answer a question which is localized or not helpful for others, the possibility is less. However, if a question is good and your answer is good enough then time doesn't matter. See for example https://stackoverflow.com/a/12853037/1723893. This answer is given after approximately a month, but it got 70 upvotes, the reason being question is good.

Also, you can share your answer:

[image]

Comment: Your answer doesn't address my questions. I understand that good answers will get upvoted, even well after another answer is accepted. I'm interested in how to review/check these mostly unseen answers and how to encourage other users to do that same.

Comment: you can share you answer to attract more traffic